# Add strings before and after for every two consecutive pattern match

Tags: regex, awk, sed, sh, csh

How can I add strings before and after for every two consecutive pattern match?

For example: I have some code like the following:

```
if (a == 5) 
    `uvm_info ("some display message");
```

Here two consecutive patterns are "if" and "uvm_info". 
I need to add "begin" and "end" only when if and uvm_info are coming consecutively.

Now I want the output to be like

```
if (a==5) 
   begin 
   `uvm_info ("some display message") 
   end
```

I can add begin end easily if I do not have to consider matching of "if" pattern using the following command:

```
awk '/`uvm_info/{print "begin"; print; print "end";next}1' test_file
```

But I need to take care of "if" pattern and if possible I want to set the indentation same as uvm_info.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight adjustment to your code would do it

```
awk 'x&&/`uvm_info/{print "begin\n"$0"\nend";next}{x=0}/if/{x=1}1' file
```

Maintain indent

```
awk 'x&&/`uvm_info/{$0=(y=substr($0,1,index($0,"`")-1))"begin\n"$0"\n"y"end"}{x=0}/if/{x=1}1'
```

Comment: Can we match the indentation of begin end to `uvm_info as well?

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression will do:

```
s/(if[^;]+?)\s+(.*?uvm.*?);/\1\nbegin\n    \2;\nend/gm
```

http://regex101.com/r/mD7gK4/3

edit:
input:

```
if (a == 5) 
    `uvm_info ("some display message"); 

if (hello) 
    `uvm_info ("some display message"); 

if (answer_toeverything == 42) 
    `uvm_info ("some display message"); 

uvm_info ("some display message"); 

uvm_info ("some display message
```

output:

```
if (a == 5) 
begin 
    `uvm_info ("some display message"); 
end 

if (hello) 
begin 
    `uvm_info ("some display message"); 
end 

if (answer_toeverything == 42) 
begin 
    `uvm_info ("some display message"); 
end 

uvm_info ("some display message"); 

uvm_info ("some display message");
```

I do not knwo what to do with the backtick (if it is accidentally in your example). if you want to suppress this in outout you may use `(if[^;]+?)[^;]*?(uvm.*?);` as search expression instead (http://regex101.com/r/mD7gK4/5).

if you have perl installed you can apply this regex to a file in this way:

```
perl -e "$_ = join('',<>);  s/(if[^;]+?)[^;]*?(uvm.*?);/\1\nbegin\n    \2;\nend/gm; print"
```

This first reads all lines from stdin and joins them into a single string, applies the regex and prints the result.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But I am not able to use the regexp you shown. Do I need to use it with sed or awk or some other way?
Sorry I am not good at scripting. And apologies if you find this question stupid.
backticks are there. I forgot to add second time.

Comment: @NavdeepSingh I added perl one liner. i do not know if its doable wit `sed` since it processes input line wise and i almost know nothing about `awk`.

Comment: Thanks Vlad for your response. I will try it using perl. Thanks a lot!!